# AWS Workspace with Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-workspaces

I want to create and manage AWS Workspace with terraform.

I have searched the Terraform documentation. But, I cannot find any documentation or sample codes.

Answer (score 0):

The support for AWS Workspace in terraform is still a work in progress. You can track the progress on the [github issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/434).

From the looks of it, there are no API calls yet from AWS

> AWS still hasn't provided any API functionality to register a
>   directory for workspaces making this impossible. Been following this
>   https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=237801 which AWS
>   has stated there is no ETA.

Comment: If you custom build it into the aws provider you could

Comment: Thankyou @ThomasVdBerge. Can you provide me the sample terraform codes for aws workspaces?